# barryvdh/laravel-dompdf page break content changes PDF

Tags: laravel, pdf, package

I am using this package barryvdh/laravel-dompdf is there any way to detect if content fits on the current page if not I want to put that content to the next page if it does not fit completly.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This is said in the documentation about the asked subject: https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf

**Tip: Page breaks**

You can use the CSS page-break-before/page-break-after properties to create a new page.

```
<style>
.page-break {
    page-break-after: always;
}
</style>
<h1>Page 1</h1>
<div class="page-break"></div>
<h1>Page 2</h1>
```

**Update, you can iterate through the items and call for example after 10 divs:**

```
<?php $i=0 ?>
@foreach($array as $object)
<?php $i++ ?>
    <!-- do something here | divs -->
    if( $i % 10 == 0 ){ 
        echo '<div class="page-break"></div>'; .... 
    }
@endforeach
```

You will have to determine yourself how many divs you can show to fill a page. An A4 paper for example has always the same height so you could make a guess of how many of your divs can be displayed on this page.

Comment: Yea thank you but I have some items inside a foreach and when I put the div inside the foreach it breaks items only one item inside a page, I need not one but as much as it fills the page as long as it is all the content of that item I do not want the item to be half in the first page half in the other when this happens I want to move that to the next page, I do not know how to explain better if you can help me thank you very much.

Comment: @shkurta you can't dynamically detect when a page end with dompdf but you could make a guess of how many divs would fit on a page. I have updated my answer.

Comment: Excellent! you are a Genius!

Answer (score 1):

This is how you do it. Put this code on your CSS

```
<style>
 .page-break {
  page-break-after: always;
}
</style>
```

Then use

```
<h1>Page 1</h1>
<div class="page-break"></div>
<h1>Page 2</h1>
```